# PDF's sent by Google script cannot be open by all

Tags: google-sheets, pdf

I send out invoices as PDFs from a sheet using the script below.

```
function EmailInvoice() 
{ var email = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("b12").getValue() 
var cusname = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("b5").getValue()
var message = { to: email, subject: "Invoice from *******", body: "Dear " + cusname + ", Please find attached Invoice. Any queries to: sales@sudburycaravans.co.uk", attachments: [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getAs(MimeType.PDF).setName("Invoice")] } 
MailApp.sendEmail(message); 
}
```

Most recipients can open the attached PDFs but around 25% cannot even though they have PDF viewers.

Any ideas please?

Thanks

Comment: I was able to open the PDF generated by your code. Are the recipients getting a specific error opening the attached PDF?

Comment: Just a wild guess, would `setName("Invoice.pdf")`, i.e. using a name with a file extension, help?

Comment: I trying to find someone who has failed to open one and see if there was a message.

Comment: Yes that's a thought using Invoice.pdf, I'll add it and see if it helps, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mkl mentioned, you can add the `.pdf` extension to the `setName("Invoice")` as `setName("Invoice.pdf")`.

The explanation is that using the native Gmail interface, the `getAs(MimeType.PDF)` sets the file to be read as pdf, but once locally downloaded, the file doesn't have the `.pdf` extension.

Another workaround would be viewing the attachment, and clicking on Print > Save as PDF.

You can also try this script as a workaround.

**SUGGESTION:**

```
function emailInvoice() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var email = sheet.getActiveSheet().getRange("b12").getValue()
  var cusname = sheet.getActiveSheet().getRange("b5").getValue()
  var sheetID = sheet.getId();
  var pdfUrl = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${sheetID}/export?format=pdf&gid=${sheet.getActiveSheet().getSheetId()}`
  const params = { method: "GET", headers: { "authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } };
  var pdfBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(pdfUrl, params).getBlob().setName('Invoice.pdf');

  var message = { 
    to: email, 
    subject: "Invoice from *******", 
    body: "Dear " + cusname + ", Please find attached Invoice. Any queries to: ", 
    attachments: pdfBlob
  };
  MailApp.sendEmail(message);
}
```

Comment: Many Thanks for the script suggestion. I will give that a try also.

Comment: Alright sure, let me know if this works.

Comment: I have sent an email to someone who previously could not open the pdf and all is well now. Many Thanks for your help Century Tuna and mkl